# using unions inside of structs to enable arrays of multiple types

Tags: c, struct, unions

I built a dynamically allocated array in C based on the struct

```
typedef struct Array
{
  int capacity;         
  int original_capacity;
  int count;        
  char **elements;   
  // element* elements; // TODO - make this work in place of the above
} Array;
```

with a bunch of different methods (below). It is by design an array of strings (char**s). Everything works perfectly and makes sense as is.

I'm told it's possible to make it an array containing multiple types by use of a union.

> How would we go about making our dynamic array be able to handle
> multiple types in a single instance? Hint: we'll probably want to make
> use of [C unions]

I have never used unions before and I can't find much online to help me for the specific use case I need.

I created this union, as I think it's what's necessary.

```
typedef union
{
  float f;
  int i;
  long l;
  char c;
  char* s;
} element;
```

And I inserted it into the struct, swapping these lines:

```
// char **elements;       // The string elements contained in the array
element* elements; // TODO - make this work in place of the above
```

As I think that's where it goes.

I compiled it to see what would happen. I got a lot of incompatible type compiler errors.

I was wondering if I'm on the right track. How you would go about using unions to make an array of multiple types? I suspect it might not require that many changes to the code, but if it is a big project, I'm happy to start from scratch and just build a few functions for it.

I am just looking for a few pointers, methods or considerations to get on the right track. Something in me suspects not a lot of refactoring is required, but maybe there is.

Methods:

```
Array *create_array(int capacity);
void destroy_array(Array *arr);
char *arr_read(Array *arr, int index);
void arr_append(Array *arr, char *element);
void arr_insert(Array *arr, char *element, int index);
void arr_remove(Array *arr, char *element);
int arr_clear(Array *arr); 
char* arr_pop(Array *arr); 
int arr_pop_no_rtn(Array *arr); 
int arr_copy(Array *src);
int arr_index(Array *arr, char *element);
int arr_reverse(Array *arr); 
int arr_sort(Array *arr);  
int arr_pop_by_index(Array *arr, int index); 
int arr_extend(Array* arr, Array* arr2);
```

EDIT:
Some of my compile errors include:

```
arrays.c:218:39: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘element’ from type ‘void *’
  218 |       arr->elements[arr->count - 1] = NULL;
      |                                       ^~~~
arrays.c: In function ‘arr_clear’:
arrays.c:278:37: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘element’ from type ‘void *’
  278 |     arr->elements[arr->count - 1] = NULL;
      |                                     ^~~~
arrays.c: In function ‘arr_pop_no_rtn’:
arrays.c:289:37: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘element’ from type ‘void *’
  289 |     arr->elements[arr->count - 1] = NULL;
      |                                     ^~~~
arrays.c: In function ‘arr_pop’:
arrays.c:304:51: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘strlen’
  304 |     int last_element_length = strlen(arr->elements[last_index]);
      |                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                   |
      |                                                   element
```

Comment: `el* elements;` What is `el`? You have shown an `element` type but not an `el` type. Please show exact complete code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and also provide the exact error msgs. The approach sounds generally fine so if you have specific errors you need to ask about those.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for that. Edited my question.

Comment: `element* elements` is an array of `element` structures. But you are assigning `NULL` pointer to each element. The elements are not pointers. Again, we need complete code. You have not even shown the code that those errors come from. We can't help effectively with code we can't see.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your variant arrays with a pointer to an array of `element` elements, or you can use a union of pointers to the possible element types, which would be more efficient in terms of storage.

In both cases, you should store the type of the elements somewhere.

You did not post the code for the various functions in your API, but much work seems required to handle the various types you declared in the `element` union.

Comment: Indeed.  `Array *create_array(int capacity);` can't work for a variably-typed array if you don't pass it the type.

Comment: Thanks! If you want the whole code, I can give it but it's 500 lines. Can be compacted to maybe 400 but that includes every function I wrote. I'll probably start from scratch and build up an array that can handle multipel types, just using one or two method-- tomorrow.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: with the proposed `element *elements;` approach, it can work as the space can be allocated and no `element` need to be initialized.

Comment: @gcr: no need to post the whole code yet... Have fun coding :)